# Wealth-lab 6 + С# = сферическая функция

Tags: c#

Пишу простой алгоритм в влд. Не могу написать сферическую функцию, которая берет в работу пару индикаторов, что-то с ними делает и выдает ответ. Ниже максимально простой код и ошибка его выполнения. Как ее победить? Сферическая функция - some_funct().
На момент вызова функции some_funct(), переменные BBUp и BBMed не равны нулю, они есть и со значениями.
[image: код]

[image: код2]

вот исправленный код, который выполняется без вопросов. но мне требуется вынести часть текста в функцию.

Comment: видимо какой-то из ваших массивов (BBUp и BBMed) равен null. Что-то большее сказать по вашему скриншоту сложно

Comment: BBMed, BBUp не равны нулю. структура - BBMed[№] = какое то число. Переправил код, убрал функцию, запустил, он выполнился без вопросов. переменные BBMed, BBUp тоже использовал. вот текст: https://content-6.foto.my.mail.ru/mail/969823/28/s-43.PNG . Можно ли в разделе protected override void Execute() написать какую то функцию? если можно то как?

Comment: @Валентин тут никому не интересны ваши картинки. Вставляйте код. Вы же не думаете, что люди будут кропотливо перепечатывать вашу программу со скриншотов в свои IDE чтобы проверить, как это работает?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

@Валентин, во-первых, вставляйте код не картинками, а текстом,
во-вторых, у вас есть несколько переменных с одинаковым именем, например две переменные *BBUp*, причем одна из них локальная, вторая статическая, что можно считать глобальной для класса.
инициализируете вы только одну - локальную. Когда вы выполняете функцию, вы в нее не передаете ваши локальные переменные, поэтому внутри нее используются - статические. А так как они не инициализированы - вы и получаете вашу ошибку.

Исправить можно, например передавая ваши локальные объекты

```
public static bool some_func (DataSeries BBUp, DataSeries BBMed){ ... }
```

и вызывая

```
some_func (BBUp, BBMed)
```

Comment: Всем спасибо, с картинками исправлюсь. public static bool some_func (DataSeries BBUp, DataSeries BBMed){ ... } <-- это помогло